# BioPython Count Error

Tags: python, biopython

I am currently working on a project for which I need to download a few thousand citations from PubMed. I am currently using BioPython and have written this code:

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import Medline
from pandas import *
from sys import argv
import os

Entrez.email = "my_email"
df = read_csv("my_file_path")
i=0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print (row.id)
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed",rettype="medline",retmode="text", id=row.id)
    records = Medline.parse(handle)
    for record in records:
        try:
            abstract = str(record["AB"])
        except:
            abstract = "none"
        try:
            title = str(record["TI"])
        except:
            title = "none"
        try:
            mesh = str(record["MH"])
        except:
            mesh = "none"
    path = 'my_file_path'
    filename= str(row.id) + '.txt'
    filename = os.path.join(path, filename)
    file = open(filename, "w")
    output = "title: "+str(title) + "\n\n" + "abstract: "+str(abstract) + "\n\n" + "mesh: "+str(mesh) + "\n\n"
    file.write(output)
    file.close()
    print (i)
    i=i+1
```

However, I receive the following error when this code is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_file_path", line 13, in <module>
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed",rettype="medline",retmode="text", id=row.id)
  File "/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/biopython-1.68-py3.5-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 176, in efetch
    if ids.count(",") >= 200:
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Here are the first few columns of the CSV file:

```
id
10029645
10073846
10078088
10080457
10088066
...
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a sample of the CSV you are converting into a DF - the first 5 rows or so should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is at

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed",rettype="medline",retmode="text", id=row.id)
```

From the documentation

> **id**
>
> UID list. Either a single UID or a comma-delimited list of UIDs

[From the examples I see](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-module.html), `id` is a string, not a `numpy.int64` out of a pandas dataframe. You should convert that `row.id` to a string